# Grouping booleans

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to collect data which is classified in many groups. When I receive the first item of a group, I want to put a boolean as TRUE, to indicate there is some info into that group or not.

My first approach was writing a method to return that boolean for each group I want to check. But since I have 8 groups, I though about giving a different scope: I defined an ENUM, and created a Map having that ENUM as key and the boolean as the Value:

```
enum dataNames{TITLE, AUTHOR, SOURCE, ELEVATION, SPEED, SATELLITES, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE}; //etc

private Map<dataNames, Boolean> availableData;
```

And then I check the state of each boolean calling this method:

```
public boolean isDataAvailable (dataNames name){
        return availableData.containsKey(name);
    }
```

For example:

```
public void addElevationValue(double elevationValue){
        if(!isDataAvailable(dataNames.ELEVATION)) availableData.put(dataNames.ELEVATION, true);
        elevacion.add(elevationValue);
    }
```

My question is: is this a good aproach, or should I stay with a method for each boolean I want to check? And... why? (I just want to learn)

Comment: Why don't you just check whether `elevacion` (a list?) is empty or not?

Comment: You can use a `Set<dataNames>` and use the existence in the set to see whether or not you have data for that collection.  A `Map` with a boolean that is always true is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh and it should be `DataName` (Capital D) if you are going to match Java naming standards.  I also recommend no "s" on the end.  ex: `DataName.TITLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a map to tell you if data is available or not?

It looks like you are storing your data in a collection, so if this collection is empty, there is no data available.

For example:

```
public void addElevationValue(double elevationValue){
    elevacion.add(elevationValue);
}

public boolean hasElevationData(){
    return !elevacion.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it is the same as having a method for each one. So, is this preferable to do the thing I was planning to do?

Comment: since you have separate methods for adding different types of data, it makes sense to have separate methods to check the different types of data too.